# Typescript error using react-cookie setCookie - Type '{ [name: string]: any; }' has no compatible call signatures.ts(2349)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using react-cookie in a react application with typescript but coming into the error

```
Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '{ [name: string]: any; }' has no compatible call signatures.ts(2349)
```

when using `setCookie` as

```
const [setCookie] = useCookies(['example']);
const onLanguageSelect = (data: any) => {
  setCookie('example', data.value, { path: '/' });
};
```

the error is on the `setCookie` line.

How can I fix this error? Reading on this issue in other questions hasn't helped but if you know of a resource that can put me in the right direction, that would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the react-cookie readme:

```js
const [cookies, setCookie, removeCookie] = useCookies(['cookie-name']);
```

`setCookie` is the **second** item of the returned array.

In your code you get the first item, `cookies`, which you rename to `setCookie`.

The fix:

```js
const setCookie = useCookies(['example'])[1];
```

Be carefull with array destructuring, it's quite sexy but may be sometimes misleading.